# How to use MAPISendMail with gmail

Tags: c#, gmail, mapisendmail

I have a problem with using MAPISendMail with gmail. It's work really good with outlook, but my main goal to use it with gmail. Is that even possible? What I would like to do, is to open gmail with a new message with a to addres, and an attachment. If I cannot use MAPISendMail for this, is tehre any way, to solve my problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending email in .NET through Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)